# Laravel Eloquent querying pivot tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Using Laravel 5, I have a database consisting of users, conversations and messages, joined by a pivot table between the users and conversations which is called "conversation_user" (and formed with a BelongsToMany relationship). The schema is below:

```
| USERS    | CONVERSATION | MESSAGES        | CONVERSATION_USER |
| id       | id           | id              | user_id           |
| username | timestamps   | conversation_id | conversation_id   |
| password |              | user_id         |                   |
|          |              | message         |                   |
```

So basically I'm trying to use conversation_user to obtain all of the conversation_ids relating to the logged in user and then use those results to get the last message relating to that conversation.

In SQL terms this equates to:

```
SELECT messages.`message` FROM conversation_user INNER JOIN messages ON
conversation_user.conversation_id=messages.conversation_id 
WHERE conversation_user.user_id=1 ORDER BY messages.id DESC
```

However I cannot figure out how to achieve this with Eloquent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$messages = Message::whereHas('conversation.users', function($q){
    $q->where('user_id', 1);
})->get();
```

Comment: If I introduced another table into the mix called JOBS with a foreign key in the conversations table called JOB_ID, any idea how I could use multiple WhereHas?

Comment: If you specify the relationship you can just chain another `whereHas` call. Like `Message::whereHas('conversation.users', ...)->whereHas('conversation.job', ...)->get()`

Comment: Based on my table structure it didn't work...I've posted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29711549/3250992